# MySQL Update query with left join and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to create an update query and making little progress in getting the right syntax.
The following query is working:

```
SELECT t.Index1, t.Index2, COUNT( m.EventType ) 
    FROM Table t
    LEFT JOIN MEvents m ON
        (m.Index1 = t.Index1 AND
         m.Index2 = t.Index2 AND
        (m.EventType =  'A' OR m.EventType =  'B')
    ) 
    WHERE (t.SpecialEventCount IS NULL)
    GROUP BY t.Index1, t.Index2
```

It creates a list of triplets Index1,Index2,EventCounts. 
It only does this for case where t.SpecialEventCount is NULL. The update query I am trying to write should set this SpecialEventCount to that count, i.e. COUNT(m.EventType) in the query above. This number could be 0 or any positive number (hence the left join). Index1 and Index2 together are unique in Table t and they are used to identify events in MEvent.

How do I have to modify the select query to become an update query? I.e. something like

```
UPDATE Table SET SpecialEventCount=COUNT(m.EventType).....
```

but I am confused what to put where and have failed with numerous different guesses.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I take it that `(Index1, Index2)` is a unique key on `Table`, otherwise I would expect the reference to `t.SpecialEventCount` to result in an error.

Edited query to use subquery as it didn't work using `GROUP BY`

```
UPDATE
    Table AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            Index1,
            Index2,
            COUNT(EventType) AS NumEvents
        FROM
            MEvents
        WHERE
            EventType = 'A' OR EventType = 'B'
        GROUP BY
            Index1,
            Index2
    ) AS m ON
        m.Index1 = t.Index1 AND
        m.Index2 = t.Index2
SET
    t.SpecialEventCount = m.NumEvents
WHERE
    t.SpecialEventCount IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, looks similar to many things I have tried. Unfortunately comes back with the following error:


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY 
t.Index1, 
t.Index2' at line 9

Comment: using version 5.0.90-log if this helps

Comment: Problem with above is differentiating between 0s and NULLs. If there are no Events matching, then t.SpecialEventCount is set to NULL and not 0, thus you always end up with lots of NULLs in your table where you dont know whether these are zeros or have not been calculated yet.

Tried 

     Set ... = IF(m.NumEvents IS NULL,0,m.NumEvents) 

without success

Comment: Change `SET t.SpecialEventCount = m.NumEvents` to `SET t.SpecialEventCount = IFNULL(m.NumEvents, 0)`

Comment: nice, it works fine the UPDATE using LEFT JOIN statement, otherwise not

Comment: Hammerite, your comment solved the issue I was having with getting a bunch of NULL values instead of 0, which is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this saved so much for mé!

Answer (score 6):

Doing a left join with a subquery will generate a giant 
temporary table in-memory that will have no indexes.

For updates, try avoiding joins and using correlated 
subqueries instead:

```
UPDATE
    Table AS t
SET
    t.SpecialEventCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(m.EventType)
        FROM MEvents m
        WHERE m.EventType in ('A','B')
          AND m.Index1 = t.Index1
          AND m.Index2 = t.Index2
    )
WHERE
    t.SpecialEventCount IS NULL
```

Do some profiling, but this can be significantly faster in some cases.

Comment: Profiling in advance on update statements is not widely supported, so often it has to be actually executed to test it.
An update of all 119465 rows in a table joined in this way to a table of 1.8 milion rows took 0.7680 seconds using your method, and 0.6227 seconds using Hammerite's method. No drama there, i would say. Please do note that this could be situation specific.
I gave it another try linked to a 18 mil table, there the numbers where 23.9238 seconds and 9.1261 seconds respectively. No improvements.

Answer (score 1):

my example

```
update card_crowd  as cardCrowd
LEFT JOIN 
(
select cc.id , count(1) as num
from card_crowd cc LEFT JOIN 
card_crowd_r ccr on cc.id = ccr.crowd_id
group by cc.id
) as tt
on cardCrowd.id = tt.id
set cardCrowd.join_num = tt.num;
```