# Running an SQL query inside the SET keyword to set number of records returned by the query

Tags: mysql, sql

In just one `UPDATE` query, is it possible to `SET` a value based on an SQL query result?

This is the query I have in mind which does not work:

```
UPDATE items SET itemcode=CONCAT('XYZ',(SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr FROM items
       WHERE itemcode!=''),'GZ') WHERE itemid=123;
```

This isn't the actual query but the purpose of using one query is to prevent a race condition when I try to run two consecutive queries.

After inserting records in the `items` table, I will need to update some of the created items and input an item code that increments. So it depends on the number of items in the table with an empty `itemcode`.

Answer (score 2):

To properly avoid race conditions, you can use `LOCK TABLE` and transactions in order to ensure a consistent result.

In your query

```
UPDATE items SET itemcode=CONCAT('XYZ',(SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr FROM items
   WHERE itemcode!=''),'GZ') WHERE itemid=123;
```

you're selecting records with a given property from `items`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr FROM items WHERE itemcode!=''
```

and then associating the `itemcode` of `itemid` 123 to XYZGZ.

This you can also do with a `UPDATE JOIN` between `items` and `ctr`:

```
UPDATE items JOIN ( 
   SELECT CONCAT('XYZ', COUNT(*), 'GZ') AS newcode FROM items
       WHERE itemcode!='') AS dummy
SET itemcode = dummy.newcode WHERE itemid = 123;
```

Or in MySQL (and using LOCK TABLES), you can `SELECT` the count into a temporary variable, then assign `itemcode` to that variable:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE items ( itemid integer, itemcode varchar(32) );
mysql> INSERT INTO items VALUES ( 1, 'one' ), ( 2, 'two' ), ( 123, 'and 123');
mysql> LOCK TABLE items WRITE;
mysql> BEGIN WORK;
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @x FROM items WHERE itemcode != '';
mysql> UPDATE items SET itemcode=CONCAT('XYZ',@x,'GZ') WHERE itemid = 123;
mysql> COMMIT WORK;
mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;


mysql> SELECT * FROM items;
+--------+----------+
| itemid | itemcode |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | one      |
|      2 | two      |
|    123 | XYZ3GZ   |
+--------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

A shorter way of doing same, without explicit locking:

```
mysql> BEGIN WORK;
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @x FROM items WHERE itemcode != '' FOR UPDATE;
mysql> UPDATE items SET itemcode=CONCAT('XYZ',@x,'GZ') WHERE itemid = 123;
mysql> COMMIT WORK;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning race conditions.. but still the COUNT(*) with an negated operator would require to scan most of the table on InnoDB engine so it can take an well...

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a query you might want to use for this case:

```
UPDATE
    Table AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            Index1,
            Index2,
            COUNT(EventType) AS NumEvents
        FROM
            MEvents
        WHERE
            EventType = 'A' OR EventType = 'B'
        GROUP BY
            Index1,
            Index2
    ) AS m ON
        m.Index1 = t.Index1 AND
        m.Index2 = t.Index2
SET
    t.SpecialEventCount = m.NumEvents
WHERE
    t.SpecialEventCount IS NULL
```

It was originally posted by @Hammerite [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022405/mysql-update-query-with-left-join-and-group-by).

Answer (score 0):

### Found the answer!

The subquery should not be inside the `SET` part because I was trying to access the same table. The query in the question returns the following error:

```
#1093 – You can’t specify target table ‘items’ for update in FROM clause.
```

### Solution:

```
UPDATE items,(SELECT COUNT(*) as ctr FROM items WHERE itemcode!='') temp
        SET itemcode=CONCAT('XYZ',temp.ctr+1,'GZ') WHERE itemid=123;
```

Source:
http://7php.com/mysql-update-select-statement-1093/