# Change a MySql Select/Inner-Join with Group By into an Update?

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I am doing an Inner-Join between two tables to try to create a Group_Concat from the first Table:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat('!"',LJ.Name1,'"') separator ' ') FROM `Table1` BC
Inner Join `Table2` LJ
On LJ.Name like concat(BC.Name,' %')
and LJ.Field_S=BC.Field_S
Where LJ.Type='Person'
Group by BC.Field_S,BC.Name`
```

The problem is when I try to make this an `Update`as is the purpose MySql does not like the `Group By` apparently inside an `Update`.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) seems to be down so I can't make an example until I can find an alternative but in the interim was wondering if there is some "standard" way of converting this kind of `Select Inner Join` into an `Update Inner Join`.

Comment: Until you can be more complete via SQLFiddle, please nevertheless show the update you are trying to do. Give your table definitions. Give the error message. Read re [mcve]s and act on it.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks, I was hoping SqlFiddle would be up to simplify the explanation. In reading similar questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022405/mysql-update-query-with-left-join-and-group-by)  I notice there is a way to do this with a subquery which itself is difficult. My fast solution was to do a `Create Table as` using the Select and then doing a simply `Inner Join` using the new table.