# Access Update query with left join and group by

Tags: ms-access, join, null

The query that selects the 42 unique task codes from [Task_History_Report_063018] that DO NOT currently exist in the [Task Code Dict] is

```
SELECT Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code]
FROM Task_History_Report_063018 LEFT JOIN [Task Code Dict] 
ON Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code] = [Task Code Dict].[Task Code]
WHERE ((([Task Code Dict].[Task Code]) Is Null))
GROUP BY Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code];
```

When I convert this to the following update query:

```
UPDATE Task_History_Report_063018 LEFT JOIN [Task Code Dict] 
ON Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code] = [Task Code Dict].[Task Code] 
SET [Task Code Dict].[Task Code] = [Task_History_Report_063018].[Task code]
WHERE ((([Task Code Dict].[Task Code]) Is Null));
```

It attempts to update the dictionary with 201 NON-UNIQUE task codes. These are the 42 unique codes, expanded by their duplicates.

I tried:

```
UPDATE (SELECT Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code]
FROM Task_History_Report_063018
GROUP BY Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code]) as GroupedTasks 
LEFT JOIN [Task Code Dict] 
ON GroupedTasks.[Task code] = [Task Code Dict].[Task Code] SET [Task Code Dict].[Task Code] = GroupedTasks.[Task code]
WHERE ((([Task Code Dict].[Task Code]) Is Null));
```

When I select the Datasheet View I see the 42 null records for the corresponding unique task codes that are new, but when I attempt to execute I get an error that says:

Operation must use an updateable query.

I think this question was addressed here for MySQL, but the syntax didn't totally translate... [MySQL Update query with left join and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022405/mysql-update-query-with-left-join-and-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, fixed this. For some reason I was trying to do an update query when I was supposed to be doing and append. This got the job done:

```
INSERT INTO [Task Code Dict] ( [Task Code] )
SELECT DISTINCT Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code]
FROM Task_History_Report_063018 LEFT JOIN [Task Code Dict] 
ON Task_History_Report_063018.[Task code] = [Task Code Dict].[Task Code]
WHERE ((([Task Code Dict].[Task Code]) Is Null));
```

Comment: Since you have answered your own question and have solved the problem, could you please mark this answer as the solution so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the question list?