# Update Query with Static Value and Dynamic Value

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to update two columns on a table, in MS Access using Microsoft 365.  One value is static and one is based on a select query.  However I continue to get `Operation must use an updateable query` error message.  Below is my query:

```sql
UPDATE tblBuckets AS e
SET e.DiscountExclusion = "SpecialDisc", e.DrugSpecDisc = (
  SELECT sd.[Discount Rate]
  FROM  tblDrugSpecDis AS sd
  INNER JOIN tblClaims AS s ON sd.[Drug ID] = LEFT(s.ndc11code, sd.[Length of Drug ID])
  WHERE sd.Indicator = 'N'
)
WHERE e.sourceclaimid IN (
  SELECT s.sourceclaimid 
  FROM tblClaims AS s
  INNER JOIN tblDrugSpecDis AS sd ON sd.[Drug ID] = LEFT(s.ndc11code, sd.[Length of Drug ID])
  WHERE sd.Indicator = 'N'
)
```

Comment: Please add the tag of the DB-System that you are using!

Comment: The solution in this thread answered helped me correct my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022405/mysql-update-query-with-left-join-and-group-by